# r - apply a function on data n number of times

Tags: r, function, iteration

I would like to apply the same function certain number of times on a vector using the output from the function every time.

A simplified example with a simple function just to demonstrate:

```
# sample vector
a <- c(1,2,3)

# function to be applied n times
f1 <- function(x) {
  x^2 + x^3
 }
```

I would like to apply `f1` on `a`, `n` number of times, for example here lets say 3 times.

I heard `purrr::reduce` or `purrr::map()` might be a good idea for this but couldn't make it work.

The desired output if `n = 3` would be equal to `f1(f1(f1(a)))`.

Comment: You should make your function `return` something.

Comment: @apitsch, it does, implicitly. That is, if the last line of code in the function block is `x^2 + x^3`, this is equivalent to both `return(x^2 + x^3)` and `tmp <- x^2 + x^3 ; return(tmp)`.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for letting me know. Glad to learn something new.

Comment: BTW: @apitsch, this *can* bite you: if the function does a partial assignment such as `mtcars$cyl <- mycars$cyl + 1`, then the value returned is not `mtcars`, it's `mtcars$cyl`, a common mistake to make. You can see that the assignment is *invisibly* returning the values assigned by wrapping the call in just parens, as in (on your console) `(mtcars$cyl <- mycars$cyl + 1)`. For this reason, many (as you were suggesting) feel that explicit `return(...)` statements can be a good thing.

Comment: @r2evans `return` is needed only in special cases... in general case, the last expression evaluated within a function is returned. You need an explicit `return` statement only if you want to break out of the function and return a value before that. `return` does not affect the "visibility / invisibility" of the returned value: for example, assignment returns the value that was assigned but does so *invisibly*. Try `fun <- function(x) return(a<-x)` -- now `fun(3)==3` equals `TRUE` but `fun(3)` does not show any value on the screen. But `fun <- function(x) (a<-x)` would behave differently.

Comment: ??? I already mentioned the last expression thing, and I never said it was required. The (in)visibility of the value returned from an assignment operator is not affected by `return`, true, but it is always a misconception of how the "last expression" is misinterpreted. The only thing I see that I could have been clearer about in that comment was *"the assignment is invisibly returning"* ... I can see how that might be misconstrued, but if you take it literally, an assignment operation *does* return its values invisibly, which is distinct from the enveloping function's return mechanism.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's use `Reduce` (no external library requirements, generally good performance). I'll modify the function slightly to accept a second (ignored) argument:

```
f1 <- function(x, ign) x^2 + x^3

Reduce(f1, 1:3, init = a)
# [1] 1.872000e+03 6.563711e+09 1.102629e+14
```

Here's what's happening. `Reduce`:

> uses a binary function to successively combine the elements of a given vector and a possibly given initial value.

The first argument is the function to use, and it should accept two arguments. The first is the value from the *previous* execution of the function in this reduction. On the first call of the function, it uses the `init=` value provided.

- First call:

  ```
  f1(c(1,2,3), 1)
  # [1]  2 12 36
  ```
- Second call:

  ```
  f1(c(2,12,36), 2)
  # [1]    12  1872 47952
  ```
- Third call:

  ```
  f1(c(12,1872,47952), 3)
  # [1] 1.872000e+03 6.563711e+09 1.102629e+14
  ```

The second argument `1:3` is used just for its length. Anything of the proper length will work.

If you don't want to redefine `f1` just for this reduction, you can always do

```
Reduce(function(a,ign) f1(a), ...)
```

---

Benchmark:

```
library(microbenchmark)
r <- Reduce(function(a,b) call("f1", a), 1:3, init=quote(a))
triple_f1 <- function(a) f1(f1(f1(a)))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  base = Reduce(function(a,ign) f1(a), 1:3, a),
  accum = a %>% accumulate(~ .x %>% f1, .init = f1(a)) %>% extract2(3),
  reduc = purrr::reduce(1:3, function(a,ign) f1(a), .init=a),
  whil = { 
    i <- 1
    a <- c(1,2,3)
      while (i < 10) {
        i <- i + 1
        a <- f1(a)
      }
    },
  forloop = {
    out <- a
    for(i in seq_len(3)) out <- f1(out)
  },
  evaluated = {
    r <- Reduce(function(a,b) call("f1", a), 1:3, init=quote(a))
    eval(r)
  },
  precompiled = eval(r),
  anotherfun = triple_f1(a)
)
# Unit: microseconds
#         expr      min        lq       mean    median        uq      max neval
#         base    5.101    7.3015   18.28691    9.3010   10.8510  848.302   100
#        accum  294.201  328.4015  381.21204  356.1520  402.6510  823.602   100
#        reduc   27.000   38.1005   57.55694   45.2510   54.2005  747.401   100
#         whil 1717.300 1814.3510 1949.03100 1861.8510 1948.9510 2931.001   100
#      forloop 1110.001 1167.1010 1369.87696 1205.5010 1292.6500 9935.501   100
#    evaluated    6.702   10.2505   22.18598   13.3015   15.5510  715.301   100
#  precompiled    2.300    3.2005    4.69090    4.0005    4.5010   26.800   100
#   anotherfun    1.400    2.0515   12.85201    2.5010    3.3505 1017.801   100
```

Comment: definitely what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

```
i <- 1

while (i < 10) {
  i <- i + 1
  x <- f(x)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `accumulate`

```
library(tidyverse)
n <- 3
a %>% 
  accumulate(~ .x %>%
                 f1, .init = f1(a)) %>%
  extract2(n)
#[1] 1.872000e+03 6.563711e+09 1.102629e+14
```

NOTE: `accumulate` is similar to the `base R` option `Reduce` with `accumulate = TRUE`

checking with the OP's output

```
f1(f1(f1(a)))
#[1] 1.872000e+03 6.563711e+09 1.102629e+14
```

---

Or use a `for` loop (no external libraries used)

```
out <- a
for(i in seq_len(n)) out <- f1(out)
out
#[1] 1.872000e+03 6.563711e+09 1.102629e+14
```

Comment: can this be done without keeping the intermediate results. With `purrr::map` maybe ?

Comment: @adl  `map` applies the function on each elements separately and not get the function to be applied on the output of each one recursively

Comment: @adl  What i meant is that `map(rep(list(a), n), f1)` gets the same output when you apply 'n' times, because the output from first is not recursively applied with `f1`

Comment: ok, but is there another package that needs to be loaded because `extract2` is not found in `tidyverse`

Comment: @adl  It is just to extract the list elements.  it is from `library(magrittr)`  I thought it is also included in tidyverse

Comment: it is in `magrittr`. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Instead of `accumulate %>% extract2`, couldn't you just use `purrr::reduce`?

Comment: @r2evans sure, it can be used.  I was thinking in line of `accumulate` at that point

Comment: Yes, but if you don't need it, why calculate it? `identical(purrr::accumulate(1:3, f1, .init=a)[[4]], purrr::reduce(1:3, f1, .init=a))` is true. (Assuming, of course, that the OP either redefined `f1` to accept a second argument or adds a wrapper around it.)

Comment: @r2evans  You changed the OP's function

Comment: and demonstrated how to do it without changing the OP's function. `identical(purrr::accumulate(1:3, function(a,ign) f1(a), .init=a)[[4]], purrr::reduce(1:3, function(a,ign) f1(a), .init=a))` using the unchanged function. Sorry, I'm not trying to debate or prove anything better, just wondering (as I learn more tidyverse functions) what value `accumulate` has over `reduce` here.

Comment: @r2evans I understand that `reduce` is better in this case.  I was thinking about gertting ` list` of `vector`s and then the OP can decide whether to select one element or multiple

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it with `Reduce`:

#### setting the stage

```
a <- 1:3
f1 <- function(x) x^2 + x^3
```

#### constructing a call and evaluating it

```
N <- 3   # how many times?
r <- Reduce(function(a,b) call("f1", a), rep(NA, N), init=a)
# f1(f1(f1(1:3)))
eval(r)
# [1] 1.872000e+03 6.563711e+09 1.102629e+14
```

#### alternative 2

```
# N defined as above
Reduce(function(x,y) y(x), replicate(N,f1), init=a)
# [1] 1.872000e+03 6.563711e+09 1.102629e+14
```

#### alternative 3 (recursive with a global-like variable)

```
doit <- function(N) {
  i <- 0
  function(fun, x){
    i <<- i +1
    if(i < N) Recall(fun, fun(x)) else fun(x)
  }
}
doit(3)(f1, a)
# [1] 1.872000e+03 6.563711e+09 1.102629e+14
```

... or even

```
doit <- function(N, fun, x) (function(fun, x) 
    if((N <<- N - 1) > 0) 
      Recall(fun, fun(x)) else 
        fun(x))(fun, x)
doit(3, f1, a)
# [1] 1.872000e+03 6.563711e+09 1.102629e+14
```

Comment: You're capitalizing on the fact that the vector length and the number of repetitions are the same, I did not assume that from the OP.

Comment: Here is another way `Reduce(function(a,b) get("f1")(a), a, init = a)`

Answer (score 0):

In Mathematica, the corresponding function is `Nest`. This snippet implements `Nest` using the `purrr` package in the `tidyverse` framework.

```r
purrr::reduce(1:20, function(last_value,new_value) cos(last_value))
```

To store values along the way, as in the Mathematica function `NestList`, here is another implementation in `purrr`.

```r
purrr::accumulate(1:20, function(last_value,new_value) cos(last_value))
```

Notice that the binary function that combines terms is simply ignoring the  new value since we only need to call the function on the last value returned. The number of iterations is specified as the vector `1:20`, indicating 20 iterations.

The last examples uses the initial value 1, however you could start with a specific value by using `.init = cos(0.95)`, for example.

```r
purrr::accumulate(1:20, function(last_value,new_value) cos(last_value), .init = cos(0.95))
```