# purrr - how to apply recursively a function n_times over one value

Tags: r, purrr

I want to apply a function f() to one value n times.

For example, if I wanted to apply this function 5 times, I'd do something like:

```
f(f(f(f(f(1)))))
```

Is there any purrr solution for that?

For example, some function y such that:

```
y( 1, f, 5)
```

Comment: a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52954442/r-apply-a-function-on-data-n-number-of-times/52955145#52955145 (no purrr solution there though)

Comment: I doubt that there is any advantage to using purrr here over a simple loop:  `v <- 1; for( i in 1:5) v <- f(v)`

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way using `purrr::reduce`. It's a bit of cheating (maybe not?) but seems to work. In the below demo I am recursively adding 3 to my initial value 5 times -

```
library(purrr)

x <- 1
n <- 5

rep(x, n+1) %>% reduce(function(x, y) x + 3)
# [1] 16
```

Here's the documentation for `reduce` -

> .x     A list or atomic vector.
>
> .f     For reduce(), a 2-argument function. The function will be passed
>   the accumulated value as the first argument and the "next" value as
>   the second argument.

By design `reduce` requires an `x` and `y` argument. While you must pass both to your function, you can choose not to use `y` like I have done. This means your function uses only the accumulated value recursively.

The intermediate steps can be seen using `purrr::accumulate` -

```
rep(x, n+1) %>% accumulate(function(x, y) x + 3)
# [1]  1  4  7 10 13 16
```

Notice that the function wasn't applied to the first instance and that's why you need `n+1` in `rep` to get correct result.

**EDIT 1:**
Here's a simplified version of above logic -

```
reduce(1:n, function(x, y) x + 3, .init = x)
# [1] 16

accumulate(1:n, function(x, y) x + 3, .init = x)
# [1]  1  4  7 10 13 16
```

**EDIT 2:**
Here's a similar but simpler base R solution -

```
Reduce(function(x, y) x + 3, 1:n, init = x)
# [1] 16
```

Answer (score 0):

Could use `purrr::map` and put that in a loop in `y`?

```
f <- function(n) n^2 # or any other function of n

y <- function(n, fun, k = 1) {

  x <- n
  for (i in 1:k) {
    x <- unlist(purrr::map(x, fun))
  }

  return(x)

}

# then to do f five times would be:
y(1, f, 5)
```

To make more robust you'd probably put some error handling in for the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I have found. It looks a little verbose, but it works.

```
  reduce(
       rerun(5, f), 
  compose)(1)
```