# Nest a function k times

Tags: r

Is there a core R function that will apply a function `f` `k` times to a given value `x`?

For example, `nest(f, x, k=3)` would be equivalent to `f(f(f(x)))`.

If not, what is the most concise / idiomatic way of expressing this in R? I can come up with several solutions (recursion, for loop, etc.), but I would like to know what is the most idiomatic solution in this language.

Comment: `nest <- function(f, x, k) { for(i in seq(k)) x <- f(x); return(x) }` is hard to beat

Comment: @AllanCameron Thanks! So it sounds like most people would just write a for loop. I am very used to working with Mathematica's [Nest](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html) and [NestList](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html) so I was a bit surprised not to find a direct equivalent in R.

Comment: @Szabolcs often in R we are working with vectors, so folks might use `Reduce` or `purrr::accumulate` to iteratively apply a function to each element in a vector. The problem is that these functions themselves only take functions of two arguments, so it is a bit convoluted to get them working recursively in the way you describe, and there is no real performance boost over a simple loop.

Answer (score 4):

A simpler option might be to do

```r
nest <- function(f, x, k) tail(sapply(seq(k), \(y) x <<- f(x)), 1)
```

For example:

```r
func <- function(x) x + 5

nest(f = func, x = 1, k = 3)
#> [1] 16
```

Or if you want to be fancy, you can use recursion:

```r
nest <- function(f, x, k) if(k == 0) x else nest(f, f(x), k - 1)

nest(f = func, x = 1, k = 3)
#> [1] 16
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Reduce`:

```r
Reduce(\(x, f) f(x), rep(list(fun), 3), init = y)
```

which is equivalent to

```r
fun(fun(fun(y)))
```

##### Example

```r
Reduce(\(x, f) f(x), rep(list(sqrt), 3), init = 5)
# [1] 1.222845
```

Answer (score 3):

An approach in `?Reduce` (The syntax is `Iterate(f,x)(n)` ):

```
## Iterative function application:
Funcall <- function(f, ...) f(...)

## n-fold iterate of a function, functional style:
Iterate <- function(f, n = 1)
    function(x) Reduce(Funcall, rep.int(list(f), n), x, right = TRUE)

## In one line:
Iterate <- function(f, n = 1){
  function(x) Reduce(function(f, ...) f(...), rep.int(list(f), n), x, right = TRUE)
}
```

Example:

```
myfunc <- function(x){x+1}

Iterate(myfunc,20)(5)

25
```

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from [r - apply a function on data n number of times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52954442/r-apply-a-function-on-data-n-number-of-times/52955145#52955145)

```r
nest <- function(f, x, k) {
  purrr::reduce(1:k, \(x, y) f(x), .init = x)
}

nest(sqrt, 5, 3)
#> [1] 1.222845
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>